# Wrong depth for transparent geometry with a lot of layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to render models and composite them into an existing image with known depth. However, one of model I use has hair made with a lot of semitransparent strands. When I render it with Cycles, depth values for some pixel on the hair have depth as if nothing is there:

[image]

That causes problems with compositing: background it showing where hair should be (using "Z Combine" node). I've tried LuxRenderer, and everything works as expected there. Is there a way to get proper depth values in Cycles? I've tried increasing transparent bounce count (both min and max). It still renders noisy depth (and perf tanks, which is a huge problem).

(exr render: https://yadi.sk/d/unyMODQ5-atJEw)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's `Alpha Threshold` setting that controls whether semitransparent contribute to Depth, Mist, UV or some other passes. Setting in to 0 makes it so every hair strand no contributes to depth. That may not be a universal solution, but it worked well enough for case described in the question.